# PHP throws PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR error but regex works in javascript, why?

Tags: php, regex

Here's the regular expression:

```
([A-Z]+(?:(?:[\w\d@#$%&;,\+\.\*!-]+)?\s?(?![a-z&;]+\s)){1,})\s(<span class="label label-inverse">.*?</span>)
```

This will match a string such as this:

```
<p>Buy Apple <span class="label label-inverse">AAPL - NYSE</span> at or under $100 per share.</p>
```

When tested in a javascript regex tester such as regexpal, it works as expected. However, the PHP preg_replace function returns null with the error PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR.

```
$string = preg_replace('~([A-Z]+(?:(?:[\w\d@#%&!;,\+\.\*\$-]+)?\s?(?![a-z&;]+\s)){1,})\s(<span class="label label-inverse">.*?</span>)~i', '<strong>$1</strong> $2', $string);
```

Why is this? Can anyone explain what is wrong with the regex in PHP and how to correct it so it functions as it does in javascript?

Comment: In PHP, do you test it against a larger document?

Comment: Btw, how did you come up with that horrendous expression? What are you trying to match exactly?

Comment: I test it against the same HTML in JS and PHP. If the regex could be optimized, I'm all ears. It needs to match the following HTML strings within large HTML docs:

`Apple <span class="label label-inverse">AAPL - NYSE</span>`
`eBay <span class="label label-inverse">EBAY - NYSE</span>`
`E*TRADE <span class="label label-inverse">ETFC - NYSE</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backtrack limitations are typically due to inefficient expressions; you should simplify it to just this:

```
~([\w\s\d@#$%&;,+.*!-]+)(?=<span class="label label-inverse">[^<]+</span>)~i'
```

It captures a word (or more than one word) if followed by a `<span>` tag; the look-ahead assertion is not captured and so it makes the replacement pattern simpler.

```
$expr = '~([\w\s\d@#$%&;,+.*!-]+)(?=<span class="label label-inverse">[^<]+</span>)~i';
$string = preg_replace($expr, '<strong>$1</strong>', $string);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zVGKNs)

It seems that the rule can be described as:

1. Match at least one title cased names before `<span>`
2. Match exactly one non-title cased name before `<span>`

So:

```
~((?:[A-Z]\S*\s)+|\S+\s)(?=<span class="label label-inverse">[^<]+</span>)~
```

Comment: This works for me in PHP. Seems like my negative lookahead was inefficient and replacing it with a positive lookhead resolved the issue?

Comment: @Slim I think it was also the nesting of that inside a `{1,}` multiplier; I found it hard to deduce the logic that went on while authoring that ;-)

Comment: Your regex alters some of matches that my original was catching. Examples:  

`<p>Hello this is Ford Motor Company <span class="label label-inverse">F - NYSE</span> at or under $100 per share.</p>`  

It should match "Ford Motor Company" in strong tags.  

`<p>Hello this is eBay <span class="label label-inverse">EBAY - NYSE</span> at or under $100 per share.</p>`  

It should match "eBay" in strong tags.  

`<p>Hello this is E*TRADE <span class="label label-inverse">ETFC - NYSE</span> at or under $100 per share.</p>`  

It should match "E*TRADE" in strong tags.

Comment: @Slim Hmm, "eBay" is an interesting exception; are there more of those?

Comment: @Slim My updated answer gives the correct results for what you have given; let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: Basically the rule is: Take any words preceding the span tag starting with the first capital letter and trim spaces. Exception: if there's a word that starts with a lower-case letter and includes an upper-case letter (like eBay), start from that word instead. The words can contain special characters like * in E*TRADE or be all caps.

Comment: @Slim That's more or less what I have done; please test it and let me know.

Comment: Very close. The capture group includes a trailing space in all cases. For example, "Ford Motor Company ". How can I trim that trailing space while still allowing for multi-word captures? Also, I see you've resorted back to using {1,} instead of the + you originally suggested :)

Comment: @Slim A trailing space doesn't matter in HTML :)

Comment: True, but it matters to me. I updated your regex to this which does the trick:  
`((?:[A-Z]\S*\s?)+|\S+)(?=\s<span class="label label-inverse">[^<]+</span>)`

Comment: @Slim You can remove the `\s?` altogether then.

Comment: really strange. My updated regex (and with your suggestion of removing the `\s?`) results in the same PHP error. However your edited regex posted in the answer above works. I'm not sure why the space I added broke it. Any idea?

Comment: You still there Jack? Any help regarding my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

It's an ugly expression. And you've heard the warnings about parsing html with regex, right?

- `{1,}` can be replaced by `+`
- `[\w\d@#$%&;,\+\.\*!-]` can be replaced by `[\w@#$%&;,+.*!-]`
- The quantifier in `(?:... +)?` can be replaced by a `*`

Frankly, I don't see a reason not to simplify it to something like:

```
([A-Z]+[\w@#$%&;,+.*!\s-]+)\s(<span class="label label-inverse">.*?</span>)
```

Or even further.

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/8), look at the capture Groups in the right pane.

Comment: FYI added demo for streamlined regex.

Comment: This works in your JS example but throws this error in PHP:  
`PHP Error[2]: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 23`

Comment: Pls try again. In the big version, I forgot to move the `-`. Fixed.

Comment: It's the preg_replace() line posted in the original question.